# Postgres - Array do tipo composto ou de uma tabela

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu uso o atributo [typrelid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) da tabela pg_type do Postgres para descobrir se uma determinada coluna é do tipo composto ou de uma tabela.

```
select t.typrelid 
from pg_catalog.pg_attribute a, pg_type t
where a.atttypid = t.oid
and a.attname = 'Relation[]';
```

Mas isso não funciona quando é um array.

Eu tenho em uma de minhas tabelas uma coluna que é um array de uma tabela e eu preciso de uma consulta que me dê essa informação... de que meu array é do tipo de uma tabela.

Aos analisadores, a pergunta é simples, infelizmente não encontrei referência na internet. Se não for me ajudar, não atrapalhe a questão, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Ola!

Existe algumas formas de resolver o seu problema, uma das mais simples e formatar o tipo usando atttypmod

Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
select t.typrelid
from pg_catalog.pg_attribute a, pg_type t
where a.atttypid = t.oid
  and format_type( t.oid, a.atttypmod ) = 'Relation[]';
```

Entretanto recomendaria reforçar essa validação convertendo dois lados para regtype

```
format_type( t.oid, a.atttypmod )::regtype = 'Relation[]'::regtype;
```

Outra forma serias fazer um join com a tabela information_schema.columns e comparar quando o `data_type = 'ARRAY'`

Espero ter ajudado!